# Never Ending Responses from the function in Augular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am using Angular 2 and I am trying to display user-nickname from the User ID.

When I call the function getUserName(userId) from comments.component.html, which then calls the auth0 service to fetch the user profile. As a result I am receiving continuous responses, and am unable to display the user-nickname. The console.log(user), displays never ending response! Comments Component is nested in feeds.component.html. Each ID can be different, therefore I have to call the function each time.

Please find the code below:

comments.component.html

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngIf="commentsArray.length>0">
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let comment of commentsArray; let i = index">
    {{getUserName(comment.comment_by)}}: {{comment.comment_text}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

comments.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FeedsService } from '../../services/feeds/feeds.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Auth0Service } from '../../services/auth0/auth0.service';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'comments',
templateUrl: 'comments.component.html',
providers: [FeedsService]
})

export class CommentsComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() commentsType:string;
@Input() editId:string;
@Input() data:any;

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _feedsService: FeedsService, private _auth0Service: Auth0Service){
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.commentsArray=this.data.comments;
}

getUserName(userId:string){
    let userName:string;
    this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
        .subscribe(user=>{
            console.log(user);
            userName=user.nickname;
        });
    return userName;
    }
}
```

auth0.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Auth0Service {

constructor(private _http:Http, private _authHttp: AuthHttp) {
}

getUser(userId: string){
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer token');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this._http.get('https://url.auth0.com/api/v2/users/'+userId, options)
    .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

feeds.component.html

```
<div class="col-sm-12 feed-container" *ngFor="let feed of feeds; let i = index">
    <comments [commentsType]="commentsType" [editId]="feed._id" [data]="feed">
    </comments>
</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, Routing, HttpModule, ... ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ AUTH_PROVIDERS, AuthService, Auth0Service, AuthGuard, ... ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Awaiting your earliest Help.

Abbas

Answer (score 0):

You can't just return a value from an async call

```
getUserName(userId:string){
    let userName:string;
    this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
        .subscribe(user=>{
            console.log(user);
            userName=user.nickname;
    });
    // when this line is executed `userName` has no value yet
    return userName;
}
```

You can return an observable like

```
prevUserId:string;
prevObservable;

getUserName(userId:string){
  if(this.prevUserId === userId) {
    return this.prevObservable;
  }
  this.prevUserId = userId;
  this.prevObservable = this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
      .map(user=>{
          console.log(user);
          return user.nickname;
       });
  return this.prevObservable;
}
```

and the the value like

```
{{getUserName(comment.comment_by) | async}}
```

Comment: Okay no value, but why the response in continuous??? That's the main issue!

Comment: If you bind a method in the view like `{{getUserName(comment.comment_by)}}` the method is called every time change detection runs. If you change `getUserName` like shown in my answer using the `async` pipe like `{{getUserName(comment.comment_by) | async}}` should fix your example.

Comment: I tried your answer... console.log(user) shows nothing! Secondly, auth0.service is already returning an observable. Thats why I was using subscribe. Finaly I tried async in my ealier code as well, but still I am getting the same non-stop logs in console. I tried ChangeDetectionStrategy, which handles the continuous responses, but then does not update my view :-(

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I forgot to add the `return`. `console.log()` outside `map()` or `subscribe()` is not expected to print a value.

Comment: I am talking about the this console.log `getUserName(userId:string){
    return this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)
        .map(user=>{
            console.log(user);
            return user.nickname;
    });
}`. This displays nothing!!!

Comment: "auth0.service is already returning an observable", you can just return that observable of course. I don't know why the `console.log()` within `map()` doesn't print anything. Usually this is if the http request doesn't return any value.

Comment: Sorry I was missing return `return this._auth0Service.getUser(userId)`. I added async, but still continuous responses in console.log!!!

Comment: Did you use ´|async`?

Comment: Yes I used async. `{{getUserName(comment.comment_by) | async}}`... 1 confusion... you said **and the the value like
this.getUserName(someId).subscribe(val => this.userName = val);**, I assume that this will go in some function!!! where this part will go?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you should return the same observable as long as the same userId is passed.